# how to determinate best implementation of Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I had recently began to walk in to the Kubernetes world, there is a lot of information and most of time I get really confused;
Then I'd like to ask how I can choose the better way to administrate an infrastructure will like this:

[image]

The node and the Kubernetes master are isolated in different DMZ, the port and the direction will be opened as described in the picture.

Which way you will use to let the pods going to be executed on the right node? (for example, an Nginx pod go only on Web1 and/or web2 and a pgSQL pod go only executed on DB1 and/or DB2) use the server labeling system is good enough or have better solution to manage this?

A second doubt I have is the service have to be reachable from the external word directly from the node, so if I want to use replicas, the Web1 and Web2 should listen on same IP address the service is exposed, I suppose, or could this be managed via the kube-proxy? At the moment I thinking about configure a distributed switch between the nodes and set the external ip address of the pod one of the IP attached to the distributed switch.

It is also a good solution or have some better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which way you will use to let the pods going to be executed on the right node?

[nodeSelector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector), simplest way because you add a label to the node `kubectl label nodes k8s-node-1 disktype=ssd` which can be verified by `kubectl get nodes --show-labels` and inside pod `yaml` under `spec` you add:

```
nodeSelector:
    disktype: ssd
```

[Node affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#node-affinity-beta-feature), is more complex and more expressive as you are no longer limited to exact matches. **Keep in mind this is still a beta feature.**

> A second doubt I have is the service have to be reachable from the external word directly from the node, so if I want to use replicas, the Web1 and Web2 should listen on same IP address the service is exposed, I suppose, or could this be managed via the kube-proxy?

Here, I think you will need to use [Type LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) as a `Service`, most cloud providers have they own internal LoadBalancer [GCP](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#service-tabs-1), [AWS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#service-tabs-2), [Azure](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#service-tabs-3). There is also [MetalLB](https://github.com/google/metallb) which is implementation for bare metal Kubernetes clusters.

Hope this helps You.

**EDIT:**

OP recommends using [Node restriction](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#node-isolation-restriction) which in his example a better solution to let pods running dynamically on a sub-set of node in the cluster.

Comment: Yes, it gonna confirm to me I was understand enough good! The labels way to execute a pods in a node do not give me the flexibility to distribute the replica of a service across two node? I mean, with node selector I can say on node labeled A or on node labeled B? About the load balancer we have our own here

Comment: no @AtomiX84, with nodeSelector you specify a key and a value, so if it won't match then it will not work. You should use `Node affinity` if you want to schedule on A or B but not on C and D.

Comment: Thank you to clarify a bit more by doubt. I will read the docs you provide.